# Not all my bullets are firing

Tags: python, pygame

Thanks to the help of people on this site i have manages to get some bullets firing on a level on my platform game. The fire continuously and travel vertical until the hit the floor and then they disappear. However, i wanted to add horizontal firing bullets in that level and i have done the exact same code as my vertical bullets and yet it only fires one and doesn't fire any other horizontal bullets. It fires one horizontal bullet, goes to the boundary of my screen and after that no other bullets come after it. Any help would be aprreciated!

```
class VerticalBullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/bullet.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 7

        if self.rect.y > 520:
            bullet_list_v.empty()

class HorizontalBullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        bullet_image = pygame.image.load("Images/bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(bullet_image,-90)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= 5

        if self.rect.x < 30:
            bullet_list_h.empty()

def main3():
    TrapList.empty()
    TrapList.add(trap4)
    player.hspeed = 0
    player.rect.x,player.rect.y = 50,0

    bullet_list_v.empty()
    bullet_list_h.empty()

    FiringBullet = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(FiringBullet, 1500)

    GameExit = False

    while GameExit==False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.move(-player.speed,0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.move(player.speed,0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.move(0,-player.Jump)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.move(player.speed,0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.move(-player.speed,0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.move(0,0)

            if event.type == FiringBullet:
                bullet = VerticalBullets(400,200)
                bullet2 = VerticalBullets(500,200)
                bullet3 = VerticalBullets(625,200)
                hbullet = HorizontalBullets(700,400)
                bullet_list_v.add(bullet)
                bullet_list_v.add(bullet2)
                bullet_list_v.add(bullet3)
                bullet_list_h.add(h_bullet)

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        level3.update()

        for eachbullet in bullet_list_v:
            bullet_list_v.draw(screen)
            bullet_list_v.update()

        for eachbullet in bullet_list_h:
            bullet_list_h.draw(screen)
            bullet_list_h.update()

        if player.rect.y < 0:
            NextLevel3()

        TrapList.draw(screen)    
        trampoline.render()
        playergroup.update()
        playergroup.draw(screen)
        player.level_3_collisions(BlockListDirt2)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: suggestion: add `python` tag - and your code will be colored by SO and more readable.

Comment: It seems like a bunch of your code is doing silly stuff. Why are you emptying lists of sprites whenever a single one of them goes out of bounds? Surely you only want to remove the out of bounds sprite, not all the others? Assuming those `list`s are actually PyGame `group` objects, you probably want to call `self.kill()` when a Sprite detects that it's out of bounds. That will remove it from its groups, without removing all the other sprites in that group too.

Comment: Thanks i looked up the self.kill() function and it makes a lot more sense using that then my noob way! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

bullet_list_h.add(h_bullet)

To:

bullet_list_h.add(hbullet)

To make sure that you're adding the horizontal bullet that you just created instead of one that's not declared.

Comment: oh ummmm... that was really stupid of me... Thanks alot!